# ¿Por qué me dice "maximum recursion depth exceeded"?

Tags: python

Tengo un cajero y necesito introducir el pin de la tarjeta. Si el pin tiene exactamente 4 dígitos o exactamente 6 dígitos la máquina dirá "true" ; pero si no cumple estos requisitos, o se introducen letras dirá que es "false".

He creado un if para que en caso que se introduzcan letras sale el false.

Estoy intentando crear la función necesaria pero me pone este error de "maximum recursion depth exceeded" y estoy atascada.

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if validate_pin(pin) == str:
        print("false")

    elif validate_pin(pin) == int:
        if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
            print("true")

validate_pin(input("introduce pin"))
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estás llamando a `validate_print()` dentro de `validate_print()`. Esto es lo que se llama recursividad, y aunque puede usarse para resolver ciertos tipos de problemas, en tu caso es simplemente un error, y causa que la función se llame a sí misma en bucle infinito hasta agotar el tamaño de la pila de Python. Supongo que querías hacer `if type(pin)==str` y `if type(pin)==int`. Eso evitará la recursión infinita.

Comment: Pero por otro lado tienes otro error, y es que si `pin` es de tipo `int`, no tiene sentido mirar luego su ´len()` ya que esa función sólo existe para cadenas. Supongo que en realidad no quieres mirar si es `str` o si es `int`, sino mirar si contiene sólo dígitos o contiene algo que no sean dígitos. En ambos casos sería sin embargo una cadena. Puedes usar `pin.isdigit()` para ver si tiene sólo dígitos.

Comment: Sí! Lo que necesito es que compruebe que tiene exactamente 4 o 6 dígitos, pero no sé como hacerlo ya que la función range incluiría también el 5...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu función contiene varios errores, uno de ellos especialmente grave:

- Internamente llama a `validate_pin()`, que es ella misma, por lo que lo primero que hará será llamarse (y en esa llamada lo primero que hará será llamarse, etc...) sin llegar a retornar nunca. Estás creando un bucle de recursión infinita que acaba por llenar la pila de Python y causando el error que has mostrado.

  Y es que no necesitas para nada llamar a la propia función. Simplemente quieres saber si la cadena `pin` es o no es una secuencia de dígitos (y no si el resultado de llamar a `validate_pin()` es o no es una cadena)
- Para mirar si la cadena `pin` contiene sólo dígitos intentas mirar si su tipo es `int`. Lo haces mal porque de nuevo llamas recursivamente a `validate_pin()`, cuando lo que deberías hacer para ver si el tipo es `int` sería `if type(pin)==int`. Pero es que eso tampoco sería correcto porque no es lo mismo mirar si un dato es un entero, que mirar si una cadena contiene sólo dígitos. En tu caso `pin` va a ser siempre una cadena, nunca un `int`, pero puedes mirar si contiene solo dígitos usando `pin.isdigit()`
- De la misma forma, mirar si es de tipo `str` no equivale a mirar "si tiene letras". Pero esto se resuelve por si solo usando `pin.isdigit()` ya que si esta función te da  `False` es que no son sólo dígitos lo que hay en el pin, y por tanto que habrá letras u otros símbolos.
- Por último las funciones no deberían imprimir resultados, sino *retornarlos*, ya que esto las hace más útiles. El programa que llama a la función recibiría el valor retornado que puede usar para imprimirlo, o para otras cosas. Luego daré un ejemplo.

La función que buscas sería por tanto así:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
   if pin.isdigit():
      if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin)==6:
         return True
   return False
```

Es decir, primero miras si la cadena está compuesta sólo por dígitos y en ese caso que la longitud sea 4 ó 6. Sólo si todo ello se cumple retornas `True`. Si no, retornas `False`. En vez de dos `if` anidados podría haber usado uno solo con una condición que utilice `and`.

Ahora puedes usarlo así para imprimir el resultado:

```
print(validate_pin(input("introduce pin")))
```

pero el h echo de que la función te lo haya *retornado* la hace más útil, pues también puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
ok = False
while not ok:
  pin = input("Introduce pin")
  if validate_pin(pin):
     print("OK, pin válido")
     ok = True
  else:
     print("El pin no es válido, introdúzcalo de nuevo")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda! Me ha servido :) Ya he visto cómo me he complicado el código cuando en realidad era más facil de lo que pensaba

Comment: @irene1509 considera también probar la técnica de FAIL-FAST. Básicamente consiste (entre otras cosas) invertir el condicional IF para que falle pronto. Es decir, que evalúes la condición de error primero, y sino falla entonces continuas por donde quieres. De esta forma puedes cazar bugs y errores antes de tiempo. En la respuesta de abulafia sería `if not pin.isdigit(): return False` y lo mismo en el while, `if not validate_pin(pin): print(...) else: print("ok")`

Comment: ¿No podría simplificarse a simplemente `return pin.isdigit() and len(pin) in [4,6]`?

Comment: Creo que no, ya que usando el comando len estarías incluyendo el 5 también no? El cajero no acepta pin de 5 dígitos

Comment: No, porque `len(pin) in [4,6]` comprueba pertenencia o "existencia" si lo entiendes mejor. Básicamente `len(pin)` devuelve la longitud de la cadena, y `in [4,6]` comprueba si el valor es 4 o 6, porque [4,6] es una lista con los dos valores, no un rango. Así que puedes considerar esa linea como un IF comprimido que solo devuelve True si "pin" es digito AND longitud es 4 o 6. Si una de las dos condiciones no se cumple devuelve False

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Sí, y consideré dar esa respuesta, pero viendo que la OP está empezando, mejor usar expresiones booleanas más simples y `returns` más explícitos. Probablemente aún no conoce las listas ni el operador `in`, o el retornar directamente una expresión booleana le confunda.

Comment: @JoseRodriguez En este caso particular el FAIL-FAST no aporta mucha ventaja. En la condición `if pin.isdigit()`, si ésta es falsa ya no evalúa el resto del bloque y salta al `return False` por lo que equivale a lo que tú propones. Esa técnica suele ser apropiada cuando una de las ramas del if/else requiere mucho más procesamiento que la otra. En ese caso mejor detectar cuanto antes la condición que evita saltarse ese procesamiento. No es el caso aqui.

Comment: Entiendo, para este caso en particular probablemente no es necesario, pero pensé que si está aprendiendo, conocer FAIL-FAST y el "por qué" quizás le ayude a aplicarlo en otras situaciones más complejas

Comment: @abufalia en realidad sí que los conozco! Aunque no sabía cómo implementarlos exactamente... ya que eso haría el código mas complicado? Aun estoy empezando y lo que tu dices, me es mas complicado de entender